# While inserting to DB, An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This simple code gives me this error.

> *An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.*

```
    public void InsertData(List<tbOnConsignmentExamination> objBeExam)
    {
        GsecEntities db = new GsecEntities();
        foreach (var tbOnBeExamNumber in objBeExam)
        {
            db.AddTotbOnConsignmentExaminations(tbOnBeExamNumber);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says, your list `objBeExam` is already referenced by a previously created context.

Try detaching the objects from the other context. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx).

Comment: As you suggest me, i had done, but I am still little bit surprise, coz my other all code works pretty like this, why this one making pain....